# How are POST parameters handled in Spring 3 when some are in URL?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

I typically retrieve POST parameters like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(
    @RequestParam(value = "first_name", required = false) String firstName,
    HttpServletRequest request
) {
```

But what if some parameters are in the URL like `http://example.com/post/path?last_name=Smith`?  Is Spring supposed to grab all the parameters from both the URL and the POST data when `RequestMapping` is POST?

Basically, Facebook sends a signed_request parameter via POST and other parameters like request_ids at the same time via URL parameters.  I need to get both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what if some parameters are in the URL like
>   http://example.com/post/path?last_name=Smith? Is Spring supposed to
>   grab all the parameters from both the URL and the POST data when
>   RequestMapping is POST?

Yes, spring will get all parameter values (in form and url) for a POST request. but in your case

```
 @RequestParam(value = "first_name", required = false) String firstName,
```

will be null. Because in your url, the parameter name is `last_name`. :D

Comment: Ummm...  the point of my question was if Spring grabbed the parameters from both POST and URL.  `first_name` was in the POST and `last_name` was in the URL.

Comment: YES, spring will grab parameters from Form:input and url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question in a useful way, but, speaking of Linux:

1. POST parameters appear on stdin at the server;
2. GET parameters (those in the URL) appear in QUERY_STRING.

HTH